# Looping through json with multiple arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I'm pulling out images from Instagram using json and jQuery.

The json data contains objects and arrays. Somehow I can't loop though the second array on my way down to the values I need.

This is my code:

```
var request = "./myapi.php?user=jamieoliver"; //&callback=myFunction
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  dataType: "json", // or "jsonp" if we enabled it
  url: request,
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    for (var i = 0; i < response.entry_data.ProfilePage.length; i++) {
      console.log(response.entry_data.ProfilePage[i].user.media.nodes[i].thumbnail_src);
    }
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {}
});
```

The problem seens to be here: `nodes[i]` - nodes[] is an array - and my code doesn't loop through it - it only gives me the value inside the first object inside nodes[]. How do I loop through nodes[] in order to get the value of `thumbnail_src` inside each of its objects?

I don't have live data but here's a screenshot of the structure of the json response: [image]

Comment: Pleas always post *code* not images if you can.

Comment: I would rather say the better option is to use a advanced or a for loop for object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this :

```
var request = "./myapi.php?user=jamieoliver"; //&callback=myFunction
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  dataType: "json", // or "jsonp" if we enabled it
  url: request,
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    for (var i = 0; i < response.entry_data.ProfilePage.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < response.entry_data.ProfilePage[i].user.media.nodes.length; j++) {
          console.log(response.entry_data.ProfilePage[i].user.media.nodes[j].thumbnail_src);
       }
    }
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should loop again using another `for`:

```
var request = "./myapi.php?user=jamieoliver"; //&callback=myFunction
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  dataType: "json", // or "jsonp" if we enabled it
  url: request,
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    var nodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < response.entry_data.ProfilePage.length; i++) {
      nodes = response.entry_data.ProfilePage[i].user.media.nodes;

      for (var n = 0; n < nodes.length; n++) { 
        console.log(nodes[n].thumbnail_src);
      }
    }
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {}
});
```

Comment: Damn, It took me too long to answer. Well, I suggest a cleaner way to loop through the 2nd `for` using `var nodes;` so you can read and understand it faster.

Comment: This one is useful too. But isn't it possible to create some sort of function which automatically loops every array it encounters? I mean, so that we don't have to use multiple for loops?

Comment: @Meek That's a good question. I have done that in PHP, but it has to be something similar in javascript. You have to make a function which loops every array/object it finds and then run the function inside itself if it finds another array/object. However I can not think how could we use that since in your example you were looking for an specific object `entry_data.ProfilePage[i].user.media.nodes`.